# Alfresco : Format date to current time zone

Tags: java, spring, alfresco

Let's say I have a Java "Date" object. I would like to convert/format it  to the current time zone of my Spring Boot/Alfresco service application.

How can  I achieve this ? I know Alfresco does it to display the date in formularies.

For example, I have a date property set to 3 pm (UTC), the system will display "17:00:00" (5pm, french time).

I would like to get the same result but with Java.

Any idea ?

Thank you!

Comment: If you can avoid getting an old-fashioned `Date` object, do. Prefer a modern `Instant` , `ZonedDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime`. The `Date` class is long outdated and was always badly designed.

Comment: Your search engine should find a lot of suggestions for you. Prefer the suggestions using java.time, the modern Java date and time API. If you can't avoid getting a `Date`, use its `toInstant` method to get a modern `Instant` and do any further conversions from there.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know this class was outdated! Thank you for this information!

Answer (score 4):

If you could use `java.time` (Java 8+ needed), you could get the default zone id of a system with

```java
ZoneId sysDefault = ZoneId.systemDefault();
```

You can get the current time with the speaking method `now()`, in this case use a `ZonedDateTime.now()` for the time in the system default zone or apply a zone to `now(ZoneId)` if you want the current time in a specific zone.

Having a zone and/or a `ZonedDateTime`, you can safely switch between zones, the conversion will be handled by the class(es). You can use `DateTimeFormatter`s in order to alter display styles, like 24h or 12h format, double-digit units or single-digit ones and so on.

Here's a simple example for switching a datetime from UTC to Paris zone. The zones in this example are fixed, but you can use the system default zone id of your server instead of the Paris zone.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // define the zones needed for conversion, one for UTC
    ZoneId utc = ZoneId.of("UTC");
    // and a second one for Paris
    ZoneId paris = ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris");
    // create date and time of day in utc
    ZonedDateTime threePmUtc = ZonedDateTime.of(2022, 8, 5, 15, 0, 0, 0, utc);
    // display its time of day once
    System.out.println(threePmUtc.toLocalTime()
                                 .format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME));
    // then convert to Paris time
    ZonedDateTime fivePmParis = threePmUtc.withZoneSameInstant(paris);
    // display its time of day
    System.out.println(fivePmParis.toLocalTime()
                                  .format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME));
    /*
     * if you want more control over the output,
     * e.g. don't print seconds if they are zero or switch to 12h format,
     * then build a formatter with your desired format
     */
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h.mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
    // and print the formatted value
    System.out.println(fivePmParis.toLocalTime()
                                  .format(dtf));
}
```

Output:

```
15:00:00
17:00:00
5.00 PM
```

Comment: Thank you, it is very clear. I tried to use "ZoneId.systemDefault()", but it returned the UTC time zone. Meaning that the server time zone is actually UTC. I dont know why the dates are displayed in UTC+2 then... Anyway, thank you for the clear answer!

Comment: Good you tried it… You can now use this (or similar) code in order to adjust the displayings ;-)